# OpenGL in visual studio can't use clear color

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opengl, linker-errors

So, on main.cpp i have:

```
#include <iostream>

#include "SRC\Graphics\Headers\MakeWindow.h"

int main()
{
    if (!glfwInit())
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to open GLFW" << std::endl;
        std::cin.get();
        return -1;
    }
    std::cin.get();

    char name_LOL[10] = "Hi There";
    ENGINEG::Make_Window MyWindow(250, 500, name_LOL);

    if (MyWindow.Is_Closed())
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to open window" << std::endl;
        std::cin.get();
        return -1;
    }

    glClearColor(0.2f, 0.3f, 0.8f, 1.0f);
    MyWindow.Set_Window();
    while (true)
    {
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        glfwPollEvents();
        MyWindow.Update();
    }

    std::cin.get();

    MyWindow.Colose_Window();

    if (!MyWindow.Is_Closed())
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to close window" << std::endl;
        std::cin.get();
        return -1;
    }

    std::cin.get();
    glfwTerminate();

    std::cout << "Done!" << std::endl;
    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

On Makewindow.h GLFW is imported, therefor opengl should to but i still get this error while using opengl functions.

Error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp__glClearColor@16 referenced in function _main Game_Engine

Comment: Headers and libraries are completely different thing. Have you added the required libraries for the linker?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are there any other unresolved external symbols for glfw functions? You are most likely not including glfw3.lib in the linker settings. Go to project->properties->linker->input->additional dependencies, and make sure you have everything needed in there (glfw3.lib, opengl32.lib).